# Hole chart for a hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am working out of Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*, and I am unsure of how to proceed on problem III.2.A.

The problem is this: Let $X$ be the smooth affine plane curve defined by the equation $y^2=h(x)$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2g+1$ with distinct roots. Show that the map $\phi(x,y) = y/x^{g+1}$ defines a hole chart on $X$ for $|x|$ large.

Intuitively, this is clear to me. As we let $|x|$ grow large, $\phi(x,y)$ will grow small, but it never reaches 0. This is where the hole is. My question is that I do not know how to clearly show that $\phi$ is even a regular chart to begin with. Once I can do that I feel like the rest of the problem is not so bad.

Here is what I have written so far: Let $M$ be the maximum of the absolute values of all of the roots of $h(x)$ and $h'(x)$. Write $K = \{(x,y) ;  |x|>M \}$. This set $K$ is open. Then for $(x,y)\in K$ it follows that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are non-zero by our requirement on $x$.

Then somehow I would like to whisk these facts together to show that $\phi(x,y)$ is a homeomorphism of $K$ with $\phi(K)$. This is where I get lost. I tried letting $y=y(x)$. Assuming that $y(x)$ is equal to the positive branch of $\sqrt{h(x)}$, then I can write
$$
\phi(x) = \sqrt{h(x)}/x^{g+1}.
$$
Maybe from here I can use the invertible function theorem? I am not sure though, and I feel like I'm getting into the weeds a bit.

Comment: What is a hole chart?

Comment: @HankScorpio I didn't give a precise definition because I really just want to understand how to show that the map is a regular chart to begin with. A hole chart is a usual chart $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ with $V$ containing an open punctured disc $D$ such that the closure of the inverse image $\phi^{-1}(D)$ is inside $U$, and that this closure is transported via $\phi$ to the punctured closed disc corresponding to $D$. These charts pick out the places that a Riemann surface fails to be compact.

Comment: No problem, I just had no idea what it was - I'd never heard the term before.